# How to determine cause of extremely high CPU load on my Mid 2010 MacBook Pro?

Tags: macos, cpu-usage

My MacBook at times becomes extremely unresponsive, where the mouse doesn't move and then begins to move randomly (I suppose these events are being backed up, then the system tries to respond later). I have re-installed macOS from scratch, and same results. I have run uptime every 60 seconds, and here is a sample:

```
19:51  up 21 days, 17:23, 2 users, load averages: 3.05 2.97 4.08
19:52  up 21 days, 17:24, 2 users, load averages: 2.31 2.79 3.93
19:53  up 21 days, 17:25, 2 users, load averages: 2.28 2.69 3.81
19:54  up 21 days, 17:26, 2 users, load averages: 2.41 2.64 3.72
21:54  up 21 days, 19:26, 2 users, load averages: 45.63 14.38 7.99
21:55  up 21 days, 19:27, 2 users, load averages: 18.85 12.14 7.55
22:07  up 21 days, 19:40, 2 users, load averages: 63.26 26.94 13.42
 0:08  up 21 days, 21:41, 2 users, load averages: 88.60 37.63 18.42
 0:09  up 21 days, 21:42, 2 users, load averages: 36.19 31.54 17.35
 2:09  up 21 days, 23:42, 2 users, load averages: 56.03 37.23 20.38
 2:10  up 21 days, 23:43, 2 users, load averages: 21.65 30.76 19.11
 4:10  up 22 days,  1:43, 2 users, load averages: 64.40 43.73 24.81
 6:10  up 22 days,  3:43, 2 users, load averages: 72.75 46.90 27.36
 6:11  up 22 days,  3:44, 2 users, load averages: 29.99 39.28 25.75
 6:20  up 22 days,  3:52, 2 users, load averages: 65.00 46.30 29.20
 6:21  up 22 days,  3:53, 2 users, load averages: 27.92 38.92 27.60
 6:22  up 22 days,  3:54, 2 users, load averages: 11.89 32.33 25.91
 6:23  up 22 days,  3:55, 2 users, load averages: 6.41 27.05 24.37
```

The extremely high load comes when I wake the system up from screen saver state. There does not seem to be a high overall CPU usage - the top command currently shows 3-5% usage. Memory does not seem exhausted either. Here is the current output of top:

```
Load Avg: 2.23, 4.07, 11.07  CPU usage: 2.83% user, 4.71% sys, 92.45% idle   SharedLibs:     
418M resident, 79M data, 137M linkedit.
MemRegions: 91406 total, 2385M resident, 141M private, 700M shared. PhysMem: 7028M used (1618M wired), 1418M unused.
```

**Configuration**
    Model Name: MacBook Pro
      Model Identifier: MacBookPro7,1
      Processor Name:   Intel Core 2 Duo
      Processor Speed:  2.4 GHz
      Number of Processors: 1
      Total Number of Cores:    2
      L2 Cache: 3 MB
      Memory:   8 GB

Why so much CPU load? I am running Chrome with 5 tabs open, and terminal. That's all.

Comment: All I see is that load averages are very high when the system has been suspended (at 21:55). After it has resumed (at 6:20), values quickly normalize.

Comment: What version of macOS do you have running on this machine? It's an "old" Mac (I have one that's even older, mind you), so it's possible it's not quite up to the task of running Mojave or Catalina. If you have XCode on it, you can try a "sudo purge" in Terminal to clear the RAM cache. It'll also alleviate CPU usage because RAM refresh will be reduced to a minimal.

Comment: Its High Sierra.  It cannot run Mojave.  Its old - MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2010).  The Cpu busy may be a red herring - even when the numbers are low, it has the unresponsive behavior.  I don't have xCode.  How often/when should this purge command be run?

Comment: Never. You’re “wasting free memory” when you do this. RAM is used for cache, too. Cache can and will immediately be freed when more memory is required but is very useful otherwise. // If everything feels slow, check the SSD/HDD.

Comment: I have an external SSD drive which has very high latency, but it shouldn't have any system files on it...